# How to increment or decrement the minutes part of a HTML5 time input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to increment or decrement minutes part of a time input field instead of hours part by default on clicking up-arrow or down-arrow. It seems there is no attribute setting for this (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html).
I have searched to find a way to capture click event on up arrow but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my testing, I can go up/down in hours, minutes, and seconds, just by selecting them first. Are you saying you want the *default* to be minutes?

Comment: I think this is going to be completely browser dependent.  AFAIK, the browser isn't even under any obligation to _render_ up and down arrow buttons, just to enforce the format of the value returned from such an input.

Comment: Before clicking on arrow buttons select the minutes side HH:MM then click on arrow button.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Yes, I want default to be minutes.

Comment: I'll ditto what James said - as far as I know this is too low level for you to have control over.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You may be right but then is there any other way to increment minutes from up arrow by default without selecting minute part first?

Comment: @kamlesh I doubt it since there's no API in the spec for such a thing.  Plus you'd be changing the expected behaviour of such a control from the default, which is never a good thing.  It sounds like you might need to roll your own custom control if you absolutely need this functionality.